# linq combined column search

Tags: linq

I want to search records which two column combination equals to the parameter, why it does not work?

```
public RDCheck SearchByUserPlusId(string uid)
        {
            RDCheckDataContext dc = new RDCheckDataContext(_connString);
            var query = (from r in dc.RDChecks
                         where (r.login + r.id).Equals(uid)
                         select r).FirstOrDefault();
            return query;
        }
```

for example, one record in table is
id:4/login:test
So I pass parameter uid=test4 but it returns null, why?

Comment: Can you tell the types of `id` and `login` in your database?

Comment: and did you try `(r.login.toString() + r.id.toString()).Equals(uid)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ToString()` before the concatenation

```
public RDCheck SearchByUserPlusId(string uid)
{
       RDCheckDataContext dc = new RDCheckDataContext(_connString);
       var query = (from r in dc.RDChecks
                    where (r.login.ToString() + r.id.ToString()).Equals(uid)
                    select r).FirstOrDefault();
       return query;
}
```

Comment: I got it. Have to add Trim() at end of each column. But thanks man, your idea is great too.

Comment: Trim doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth he just didn't check his database very carefully, "`test `".Also his code works if the values are really `test` and `4`, without spaces...

Comment: @Magnus guys he trims this `(r.login + r.id)` and uses like `((r.login + r.id).Trim()).Equals(uid)`.You guys are thinking much professional but Steven doesn't his mistake is in his database, he shouldn't be allowing neither `id` nor `login` to have space in it I think.

Comment: @BurnAfterReading, actually its r.login.ToString().Trim()+r.id.ToString().Trim(). The table records are inserted by other applications, not my code, that's why.

Comment: @Steven I really think both ways are not the greatest solution and however they'll all work.

Comment: @BurnAfterReading Do you have a better solution?

Comment: if `id` is `int` it'll never be an empty string (no need to trim). If login is `char` you can do: `login ? ' ' : "" : login.ToString()`

Comment: @Steven Mr.Zack you shouldn't be allowing neither id nor login to have space in it I think.If that is not an option for you then there is no need to check id if it is produced by let's SqlServer etc. like Mr.Magnus pointed.